# Is it possible to add an overlay from Google Earth to QGIS?

Tags: google-earth

For a hiking project in Kyrgyzstan we're planning our trails in GoogleEarth. We georeferenced .gif-files into an overlay-file (.kmz-file). 
How can I import this file into QGIS? 
If I us "Add Vector", I only get a shapefile, where the maps are shown as monochrome squares.

Comment: you want to add kmz in QGIS ?

Comment: what qgis version you are using ?

Comment: Why don't you just use the Open Layers Plugin in QGIS save your Routes as a KMZ and import them into qgis. If you still need to import these tiles you might have to import them as a raster layer and not a vector layer.

Comment: All answers miss the point. He has used GE to georeference an image. Saved it as an kml/kmz file. If imported in QGIS you get only the rectangle vector. Question: How to export/import GE-geoferenced/overlaid image to QGIS? Best
Erik

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would fully-answer your question, but if you have vector data overlaying the map in Google Earth you have the option to export the image. At this point, the vector data is included in the exported image and you could georeference the image tile in QGIS.

In Google Earth...

1. Zoom to you area.
2. File > Save > Save Image...
3. Click the Map Options dropdown menu.
4. Select or unselect any desired elements, plus change other map image attributes.
5. Click the Resolution dropdown menu and choose a desired output resolution.
6. Click the Save Image... button and choose a location on your machine for the jpg to be saved.
7. At this point you could bring that image into QGIS and georeference it into your hiking project location. The vector data and any associated symbology will be static within the exported image so you'll have to ensure that is set up prior to the image export in Google Earth.

If the intent is to add a kmz file to QGIS, I believe it needs to be saved from Google Earth as a KML instead. Once it is saved as a KML, you can add it to QGIS and symbolize it accordingly. In Google Earth, just right click your "Place", choose Save Place As, then before saving change the Save as Type to kml instead of kmz. It is my understanding that QGIS is more friendly with KML. Hope this helps!